# How to fix Value error in a while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop, break, valueerror

I wrote a little program with a while loop statement. All lines run perfectly fine except for the last line of code which should break the loop. It always displays an error whenever Python tries to interpret it. I have tried changing rephrasing the code in multiple ways but to no avail. Could you please help me out?
This is the program:

```
prompt = "\nWhat is your age?"
prompt += "\n(Please enter 'quit' when you are finished.) "


while True:
    age = input(prompt)
    age = int(age)

    if age < 3:
        print("Your ticket is free.")
    elif age >= 3 and age <= 12:
        print("Your ticket costs $10.")    
    elif age > 12:
        print("Your ticket costs $15.")  

    elif age == 'quit':
        break
```

> It displays this when I run it:
>
> ```
> What is your age?
> (Please enter 'quit' when you are finished.) 7
> Your ticket costs $10.
>
> What is your age?
> (Please enter 'quit' when you are finished.) 8
> Your ticket costs $10.
>
> What is your age?
> (Please enter 'quit' when you are finished.) 1
> Your ticket is free.
>
> What is your age?
> (Please enter 'quit' when you are finished.) quit
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Desktop\python_work\chapter_7\movie_tickets.py", line 7, in <module>
>     age = int(age)
>           ^^^^^^^^
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'
> ```

I tried converting that value in the line which brings up the error to a string, but it still didn't work.

Comment: You're trying `int("quit")` which is no good

Comment: You're converting `age` to an integer right away, before you know if they typed "quit".  Check that first, _then_ convert to int.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's running fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to convert `"quit"` to an `int`, which is raising the `ValueError`. Instead, you can try checking if `age` is `"quit"` *before* the `int` call:

```
prompt = "\nWhat is your age?"
prompt += "\n(Please enter 'quit' when you are finished.) "


while True:
    age = input(prompt)  # Get input

    if age == "quit":    # Check if "quit" was input
        break

    age = int(age)       # If not, convert to int

    if age < 3:          # ...
        print("Your ticket is free.")
    elif age >= 3 and age <= 12:
        print("Your ticket costs $10.")    
    elif age > 12:
        print("Your ticket costs $15.")
```

You can also change your second `elif` to `<= 12` (we already know it's `>= 3`) and your last `elif` to an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if your 'prompt' variable is integer or not.
Use the following code to check so
if ((type(prompt)==int) || (prompt.is_integer())):
//do your pricing staff
else:
//check if quit entered

Comment: Thank you so much. It's running perfectly now.